# Unable to Pull Data from Ebay Scraper Tutorial - Getting AttributeError

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm currently following a tutorial to create an Ebay Scraper from the following link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csj1RoLTMIA&t=290s

I'm mid-way through the code and suddenly notice two things about my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=gaggia+classic&_sacat=0&rt=nc LH_Complete=1'

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def parse(soup):
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
    print(len(results))
    return

soup = get_data(url)
parse(soup)
```

The above code gives me 0 results while:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=gaggia+classic&_sacat=0'

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def parse(soup):
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
    print(len(results))
    return

soup = get_data(url)
parse(soup)
```

This code gives me 58 results. Both pages are roughly the same though the second has a filter on it but both pages definately have 50 odd products on it. My first question is why do both of these have different result numbers. I was assuming they'd turn up to be the same.

Now, assuming I use the first code that gives me the 58 results, I'm onto the second part of the tutorial and currently I am facing another issue. The code currently is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=gaggia+classic&_sacat=0'

# Takes the URL from the above and requests the data from the page

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

# This will extract the information from the data we are looking to extract

def parse(soup):
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
    for item in results:
        product = {
            #'title': item.find('h3', {'class': 's-item__title s-item__title--has-tags'}).text,
            #'soldprice': float(item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__price'}).text.replace('£','').replace(',','').strip()),  # This replaces the pound sign, takes away any commas that will interfere with the float number. amd strip any spaces while changing the number to a float
            #'solddate': item.find('div', {'class': 's-item__title--tagblock '}).find('span', {'class': 'POSITIVE'}).text.replace('Sold ',''),
            'bids': item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__bids s-item__bidCount'}).text,
            #'link': item.find('a', {'class': 's-item__link'})['href'],
    }
        print(product)
    return

soup = get_data(url)
parse(soup)
```

The problem is that for some reason, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\EbayCameraPriceChecker\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    parse(soup)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\EbayCameraPriceChecker\main.py", line 23, in parse
    'bids': item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__bids s-item__bidCount'}).text,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I've looked up on what it means but can't really understand what has gone wrong and I suspect it's something to do with my PyCharm settings or some modules that.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Each question should refer exactly to one problem, to stay clen and focused, for each additional issue a new question should be asked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Note** *Based on assumption, this answer will focus on the "real" issue with the AttributeError.*

#### What happens?

As `AttributeError` mentions you are calling `.text` method on `NoneType`.

These `NoneType` appears, cause your selection `item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__bids s-item__bidCount'})` could not find the element, what is not unusual in this case, cause some of the offers do not have the option to bid on these -> *No element, No text*

#### How to fix?

Check if the element exists - If so call `.text` method else set your variable to `None` or what ever you like to assaign to it.

```
'bids':  item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__bids s-item__bidCount'}).text if item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__bids s-item__bidCount'}) else None,
```

or

```
'bids':  bids.text if (bids := item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__bids s-item__bidCount'})) else None,
```

#### Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=gaggia+classic&_sacat=0'

# Takes the URL from the above and requests the data from the page

def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

# This will extract the information from the data we are looking to extract

def parse(soup):
    results = soup.select('ul.srp-results li')
    for item in results:
        product = {
            #'title': item.find('h3', {'class': 's-item__title s-item__title--has-tags'}).text,
            #'soldprice': float(item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__price'}).text.replace('£','').replace(',','').strip()),  # This replaces the pound sign, takes away any commas that will interfere with the float number. amd strip any spaces while changing the number to a float
            #'solddate': item.find('div', {'class': 's-item__title--tagblock '}).find('span', {'class': 'POSITIVE'}).text.replace('Sold ',''),
            'bids':  bids.text if (bids := item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__bids s-item__bidCount'})) else None,
            #'link': item.find('a', {'class': 's-item__link'})['href'],
    }
        print(product)
    return

soup = get_data(url)
parse(soup)
```

#### Output

```
{'bids': None}
{'bids': None}
{'bids': None}
{'bids': '9 bids'}
{'bids': None}
{'bids': '0 bids'}
{'bids': None}
{'bids': '0 bids'}
{'bids': None}
...
```